# draw security protocol

Tags: technical-drawing

It's about authenticated key exchange protocol, there are two parties party A and party B,they exchange some messages. At the end they compute the shared keys SK.

[image: screenshot]

I know that it's vey cool to use Latex to set type, I really want to learn it. Any one can give me some advices?
please help me! 
thanks

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SX! I would suggest you rephrase your question into a more specific request. There are plenty of ways to "draw" that protocol in LaTeX, and knowing what you want in more detail might make it easier to help you.

Answer (score 7):

The symbols are not very clear in the image; just change them if needed.

The idea is to build an array with three columns.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{@{}l@{}c@{}l@{}}
\toprule
\hat{A} && \hat{B} \\
A_1=g^{a_1},\quad A_2=g^{a_2} &&
B_1=g^{b_1},\quad B_2=g^{b_2} \\
\bar{x}\gets_R \mathbb{Z}_q,\quad x=H_1(\bar{x},a_1,a_2) &&
\bar{y}\gets_R \mathbb{Z}_q,\quad y=H_1(\bar{y},b_1,b_2) \\
& \xrightarrow{\textstyle X=g^x} \\
& \xleftarrow {\textstyle Y=g^y} \\
\mathit{sid}=(X,Y,\hat{A},\hat{B}) &&
\mathit{sid}=(X,Y,\hat{A},\hat{B}) \\
Z_1=(YB_1)^x,\quad Z_2=(YB_2)^x &&
Z_1=X^{y+b_1},\quad Z_2=X^{y+b_2} \\
Z_3=Y^{x+a_1},\quad Z_4=Y^{x+a_2} &&
Z_3=(XA_1)^y,\quad Z_4=(XA_2)^y \\
\mathit{SK}=H(Z_1,Z_2,Z_3,Z_4,\mathit{sid}) &&
\mathit{SK}=H(Z_1,Z_2,Z_3,Z_4,\mathit{sid}) \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Alex If you consider egreg's answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark to its left. In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).